# Merging and averaging tables in a database (Python)

Tags: python, database, sqlite, merge, average

I would like to **merge and average** the values in different database tables using Python. My database database.db contains tables named in the following way: 'STATE'_'TOWN'. For example, some table names are:

```
CALIFORNIA_SANFRAN

CALIFORNIA_LOSANGELES

CALIFORNIA_SANDIEGO

...
```

To illustrate, the `CALIFORNIA_SANFRAN` table contains the following (example) data:

```
Date (PRIMARY KEY)      Morning    Day    Evening   Night
01.01.2014              0.5        0.2     0.2      0.1
02.01.2014              0.6        0.1     0.2      0.2
...
```

and the `CALIFORNIA_LOSANGELES` table contains:

```
Date (PRIMARY KEY)      Morning    Day    Evening   Night
01.01.2014              0.3        0.4     0.4      0.3
02.01.2014              0.4        0.3     0.1      0.2
...
```

ect.

From these tables I would like to **obtain one table named after the State** (CALIFORNIA) in a separate database (let's call it database2.db) **with the averages of all the values in tables** `CALIFORNIA_SANFRAN, CALIFORNIA_LOSANGELES, CALIFORNIA_SANDIEGO` for each date. I.e. I want database2.db, table '`CALIFORNIA`' to contain something like:

```
 Date (PRIMARY KEY)      Morning    Day    Evening   Night
    01.01.2014              0.4     0.3     0.3      0.2
    02.01.2014              0.5     0.2     0.15     0.2
    ....
```

I haven't been able to find anything that I can use online so far so any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. I've used and am most familiar with using SQLite to work with databases from Python.

Answer (score 1):

You have a huge design flaw in your database table structure. Tables are not things that you dynamically create and drop while naming them dynamically. An example of better database structure could be

```
State       Town        Date         Morning    Day    Evening   Night
California  Los Angles  01.01.2014   0.5        0.2     0.2      0.1
California  San Diego   01.01.2014   0.6        0.1     0.2      0.2

Primary Key (State, Town, Date)
```

Second Table ( Do not require  a new database)

```
State       Date         Morning    Day    Evening   Night
California  01.01.2014   0.5        0.2     0.2      0.1
California  01.01.2014   0.6        0.1     0.2      0.2
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    avg(Morning) as a_morning,
    avg(Day) as a_day,
    avg(Evening) as a_evening,
    avg(Night) as a_night,
from 
    YOUR_TABLE_NAME
WHERE
    State = "California"
    AND
    Date = "2015-01-01"
```

You can have a more generic query using group by

```
SELECT 
    State
    Date
    avg(Morning) as a_morning,
    avg(Day) as a_day,
    avg(Evening) as a_evening,
    avg(Night) as a_night,
from 
    YOUR_TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY
    State, Date
```

which will group the data according to `State` and `Date` then aggregate the average of each group.

Answer (score 0):

you mean this?

```
CREATE TABLE CALIFORNIA AS 

SELECT 
A.DATE,
avg(A.MORNING, B.MORNING) AS MORNING,
avg(A.DAY, B.DAY) AS DAY,
avg(A.EVENING, B.EVENING) AS EVENING,
avg(A.NIGHT, B.NIGHT) AS NIGHT,

FROM CALIFORNIA_LOSANGELES  A
INNER JOIN CALIFORNIA_SANFRAN B
ON A.DATE = B.DATE
```